# Windows Authentication issue on Test server

Tags: asp.net

We have a web application developed for use on the intranet of our client. There is no login page, hence there is no Forms authentication.

The application creates a number of records which have to be stored in the DB along with the name of the currrently logged in user. For this we have enabled windows authentication which works just fine in our development environment - and I assume, that when this is deployed on the envinronment of the client, it will work too.

The problem is, that when we host this on a test server, we need to give public IP access to the clients to check it out - and hence the virtual directory is configured to allow "anonymous access".  This obviously causes a problem for us while storing the records since we are not able to capture the login name for the person who is creating/testing this application.

If we enable windows authentication for the test machine, then anyone who tries to access the app through the public IP gets a login window popup which we dont want.

Any ideas on how to capture the logged in user name for this scenario  ?

Comment: If you can give them VPN access to your network it would work with Windows authentication. Or you could just give them a username on your domain to use.

Comment: So that is to say that,  I will disable anonymous authentication, enable windows authentication, and then create a new user id/password for them on that machine so that they can use that whenever they access the site from public IP ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your design, user should log on a windows machine in your network the server is located. For that scenario, VPN would serve best and simulate real environment.